# Views : hide thumbnail for all but one content

Tags: views

Ive created a View called "most recent articles" that are made up of 4 contents. I have the thumbnail displayed along with title, body and tags for each content. This is sorted by Most recent article by published date. How can I only display the thumbnail for the latest content (1) but the other 3 articles not display the thumbnail at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The module [Display suite](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds) gives the option to add different views mode for different rows. Here is a [video tutorial](https://drupalize.me/videos/display-suite-view-modes?p=1141) ,in this lesson you cover how one can use view modes and display suite to allow multiple options of layouts for content display. This allows a user to have a different layout of the same content for different scenarios of the site. Combining this with [views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) and you can start to see the power of display suite in action.